# get longitude X, latitude Y coordinates from German NUTS regional names

Tags: python, geolocation, coordinates

I have a set of data of German regions with their `NUTS` names.

[image]

Is there a way to get `Long X` and `Lat Y` coordinates based on their `NUTS` names in Python?

Comment: you mean using an API like google maps ??

Comment: hi, thanks for your question. to be honest, i am not really sure about the API google maps. basically what i am trying to achieve is, is there a python library/package where I can use and write some codes? as if, the inputs are the NUTS_names, and then I will get the outputs of Long X/Lat Y of those nuts_names. I came across this nuts-finder library https://pypi.org/project/nuts-finder/ , as I understand it, the inputs are the Long X/Lat X coorindates, it will outputs as NUTS_names of those coordinates. What I want, is the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have just found what I want to achieve, by using the geopy python library https://pypi.org/project/geopy/, however if there are any other suggestions/solutions, I would be glad to try them also

[Screenshot of the geopy library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK5yF.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).